# Sending a text entry through segue

Tags: swift, segue, textfield

I am sending a `textfield` entry through a segue to appear in a `textfield` on another `ViewController`. The issue I'm having is that the segue nor the sending the of `textfield` entry is working properly. I know that the segue identifier is correct as if I use `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("WelcomeSignUp", sender: nil )` it works fine. Can anybody point out an error I have made or a better method to use?

Here is the code from the first `ViewController`

```
@IBOutlet var Email: UITextField!

@IBAction func Signup(sender: AnyObject) {

    let email = self.Email.text

    if email == "" {

        displayAlert("Error", message: "Please Enter Your Email Address")

    }   else {

        func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

            if segue.identifier == "WelcomeSignUp" {

                let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! SignUpViewController

                destination.mail = Email.text!

            }

        }
        }
}
```

Code of receiving `ViewController`

```
@IBOutlet var EmailSignUp: UITextField!

var mail = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    EmailSignUp.text = mail

}
```

UPDATED CODE FROM FIRST `ViewController`

```
@IBAction func Signup(sender: AnyObject) {

    let email = self.Email.text

    if email == "" {

        displayAlert("Error", message: "Please Enter Your Email Address")

    }   

}

func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "WelcomeSignUp" {

        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! SignUpViewController

        destination.mail = Email.text!

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prepareForSegue(_:sender:)` must be an instance method, but you have declared it as a nested (and unused) function inside `Signup(_:)`.

You need to move it out so it is declared in the same scope as `Signup(_:)`.

Comment: That was unsuccessful. I also added `override func` instead of `func` as most examples show it being used, it errors stating that it does not override any methods.

Comment: "That was unsuccessful" is not enough information. Edit your question to include your new code.